# Call jQuery functions which are in a separate file

Tags: jquery, file, external

My scripts are getting to big to maintain and I want to move some of that to a separate file but cannot get it to work.

I have the following:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

some code....

initEdit(theme, isAdmin, dataAdapterCustomers, dataAdapterShops, dataAdapterOrderStatus);

some more code.....

});
```

In the edit.js file I have the following:

```
function initEdit(theme, isAdmin, dataAdapterCustomers, dataAdapterShops, dataAdapterOrderStatus) {

        $("#dateEdit").jqxDateTimeInput({ 
            width: '200px', 
            height: '18px', 
            formatString: "yyyy-MM-dd",
            theme: theme  
        });

some more code.....

}
```

When doing that I get the following error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Property '$' of object [object DOMWindow] is not a function

I tried to enclose the initEdit function with the following:

```
(function($) {
function initEdit(theme, isAdmin, dataAdapterCustomers, dataAdapterShops, dataAdapterOrderStatus) {

        $("#dateEdit").jqxDateTimeInput({ 
            width: '200px', 
            height: '18px', 
            formatString: "yyyy-MM-dd",
            theme: theme  
        });

some more code.....

}})(jQuery);
```

but then I get an error that it cannot find initEdit.

I do include the additional .js file and when I checked the source code of the file and clicking on it, it loads and therefore the page did load it. I must add that the original jQuery script is within script tags within a php file. I also run jQuery in noConflict mode.

Could it be that the edit.js gets executed before it is called from the main function?

Any suggestion would be highly appreciated!

Comment: what is the order of the js file you included

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
function initEdit(theme, isAdmin, dataAdapterCustomers, dataAdapterShops, dataAdapterOrderStatus) {

        jQuery("#dateEdit").jqxDateTimeInput({ 
            width: '200px', 
            height: '18px', 
            formatString: "yyyy-MM-dd",
            theme: theme  
        });
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is doing the job! It does not understand the $ in the separate file, as you said, it does not have reference to `code`$(). jQuery() Unfortunately this file do have a lot of $ and it is possible to replace them all with jQuery, but this is not an elegant way of doing it. Therefore the `code` (function ($){ code here... }) should do the job, I will try reordering them to ensure loading in the proper order because I do get errors with the remainder of the main file.

Comment: You are welcome, please mark this answer for future references. Thanks!

Comment: This is working for me now and I will use it because, although I have to replace all the $, it is doing the job and I can get on with it!

Answer (score 0):

Do have the right order of including .js files?
make sure the main jqueryfile is loaded first, then edit.js, and then the code which calls the function. Error looks like it don't know the jquery-syntax.

Comment: Not really. Because initEdit is executed, it just doesn't have reference to $(). jQuery() works as he uses: jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

Comment: @32bitfloat I checked it and they do load in the sequence you mentioned. I did put them that way because that was what I thought but thanks for confirming the right order, that will help me in the future!

Answer (score 0):

agree with @32bitfloat, you must have the right order of including .js files..

first time include jquery file
`<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js">`

then include your file has contains the function
`<script type="text/javascript" src="function.js">`

and then call

`(function ($){
  code here...
})`

Comment: As I understand it, the purpose of the the `code` (function ($) is exactly for these situations. I tried it, after ensuring the right include order, but it does not seems to get the initEdit function which are inside of the `code` (function ($). I am sure this has to work and I will have a look at my code to see if I can get it to work this way because replacing all the $ with jQuery will be tedious!